Yokogawa WT3000 don't boot
I have a Yokogawa WT3000 Power Analyzer which I was using with no problems and then I turned it off to take a break. An hour later, I tried to turn it on and I notice that it shows nothing on the display and the LEDs don't light up, only the source fan is heard.
I disassemble the WT3000 and measure all the voltages that are marked on the different PCBs, but they are all correct. Also, I followed the Service Manual but I can't find anything strange.
In the CPU BOARD ASSY I found an FPGA (Altera EP1C3T144C8N), which as I understand, saves its configuration in an EPCS1 memory. I measured the memory when I feed this PCB but I only see clock pulses on pin 6 and nothing on pin 2 (DATA). Can I read the memory somehow to determine if it is damaged?
Does anyone know about this power analyzer, has anyone had the same problem?

From the information in the question it isn't clear what the failure mechanism is, but for general debugging suggestions about checking if the Altera EP1C3T144C8N FPGA configuration is valid:

Check for any LED on the CPU BOARD ASSY labelled as CONF_DONE or DONE. I would expect such a LED to be ON if the Altera EP1C3T144C8N FPGA had successfully loaded it's program from the configuration memory.
Check for the presence of a connector on the CPU BOARD ASSY labelled as JTAG, being a 10 pin (2 rows of 5 pins) connector. If, so it probably accepts an Altera (now Intel) ByteBlaster II or MasterBlaster download cable. In which case if a download cable is connected the Quartus II software may be able to read back the configuration memory. Notes:

I'm not a user of the Quartus II software, and am not sure if the software is able to verify if the contents of the configuration memory contains a valid bitstream or not.
If the contents of the configuration memory has become corrupted, not sure if you will be able to obtain a file to re-program the configuration memory. The Yokogawa Precision Power Analyzer WT3000 is indicated as This product was discontinued on Mar 1, 2016, so not sure how much support you can get from the manufacturer.




The CPU BOARD ASSY does not have any LED or indicator that the configuration is complete.
From what I can observe I think I can identify the connector for JTAG. I have no experience in FPGA programming, if I connect the ByteBlaster or MasterBlaster to that connector, how can I verify if there is valid content in memory?
Finally, I can get another WT3000 which is working, could I copy the program from it to load it back into this one?

@FrancoFischer I don't have the hardware and software to test, but Quartus II: Reading back programmed file from chip? suggests the "examine" feature of the Quartus programmer should be able to do read the contents of a EPCS1 configuration flash. On a search I'm not sure if Quartus-II can verify if the contents of a EPCS1 contains a valid bitstream or not. I'm hoping that someone more familiar with Quartus-II and Cyclone FPGA will be able to give a more definitive answer

Hello Chester,
Sorry for the delay, just this week I was able to read the memory from another WT3000 and write it to a new EPCS1 memory. Now the power analyzer starts up, but requiere a firmware update. Now I'm buying a PCMCIA to compact flash to pass the last updated firmware from Yokogawa Web site.
Thanks for the help
